# Calculating the frequency of three dice rolls

Tags: python

I need to create a 6 x 6 x 6 table that has all the 216 possible three dice results. Considering that the same dice values in whatever order they come is the same result (e.g. (1,4,6) is the same as all the 1, 4, 6 transformations, i.e. (6,4,1) or (4,6,1), and so on).

Then I want to calculate the frequency of different results and print them
sorted by increasing incidence.(maybe with dictionary?)

I made this list:

```
mylist = [[[(x,y,z) for z in range (1,7)]for y in range(1,7)]for x in range (1,7)]
```

and I have all the 216 possible results.

But I can't make it work for counting them and find the same results...

Can you help me?

Comment: All you have right now is the data, not the algorithm to actually count the data.  Show us what you've done for counting the results and dealing with similar dice rolls.  (Also, are you sure what you want is a permutation?  Don't you want a combination instead?)

Comment: A few things that may help you: `Set`s are unordered collections of unique elements which could present your logic of each combination once. And `Counter` instances, well, count how often each element occurs in them.

Comment: Since a triplet always has the same number of permutations, wouldn't all of them have the same rate of incidence?

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not have to use 3-dimensional table in this case, I would do it following way

```
mylist = []
for x in range(1,7):
    for y in range(1,7):
        for z in range(1,7):
            mylist.append((x,y,z))
mylist = [tuple(sorted(i)) for i in mylist]
for i in list(set(mylist)):
    print(i,'occurs',mylist.count(i),'times')
```

Comment: That works but actually i'm asked doing it with 3d table...So i have to read the tables with (for s) maybe...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.product` to produce all the possible results from rolling 3 dices, pass the results to `collections.Counter` and then to `frozenset` to count the composition of the results while ignoring orders, and then use the `Counter.elements()` method to reconstruct the counts back to readable tuples as keys in a dict comprehension:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import Counter
{tuple(sorted(Counter(dict(t)).elements())): c for t, c in Counter(frozenset(Counter(p).items()) for p in product(range(1, 7), repeat=3)).items()}
```

This returns:

```
{(1, 1, 1): 1,
 (1, 1, 2): 3,
 (1, 1, 3): 3,
 (1, 1, 4): 3,
 (1, 1, 5): 3,
 (1, 1, 6): 3,
 (1, 2, 2): 3,
 (1, 2, 3): 6,
 (1, 2, 4): 6,
 (1, 2, 5): 6,
 (1, 2, 6): 6,
 (1, 3, 3): 3,
 (1, 3, 4): 6,
 (1, 3, 5): 6,
 (1, 3, 6): 6,
 (1, 4, 4): 3,
 (1, 4, 5): 6,
 (1, 4, 6): 6,
 (1, 5, 5): 3,
 (1, 5, 6): 6,
 (1, 6, 6): 3,
 (2, 2, 2): 1,
 (2, 2, 3): 3,
 (2, 2, 4): 3,
 (2, 2, 5): 3,
 (2, 2, 6): 3,
 (2, 3, 3): 3,
 (2, 3, 4): 6,
 (2, 3, 5): 6,
 (2, 3, 6): 6,
 (2, 4, 4): 3,
 (2, 4, 5): 6,
 (2, 4, 6): 6,
 (2, 5, 5): 3,
 (2, 5, 6): 6,
 (2, 6, 6): 3,
 (3, 3, 3): 1,
 (3, 3, 4): 3,
 (3, 3, 5): 3,
 (3, 3, 6): 3,
 (3, 4, 4): 3,
 (3, 4, 5): 6,
 (3, 4, 6): 6,
 (3, 5, 5): 3,
 (3, 5, 6): 6,
 (3, 6, 6): 3,
 (4, 4, 4): 1,
 (4, 4, 5): 3,
 (4, 4, 6): 3,
 (4, 5, 5): 3,
 (4, 5, 6): 6,
 (4, 6, 6): 3,
 (5, 5, 5): 1,
 (5, 5, 6): 3,
 (5, 6, 6): 3,
 (6, 6, 6): 1}
```

Comment: Please don't abuse comprehensions like that

Comment: This is a normal usage of comprehension. An abuse of comprehension would be to use the side effects of functions inside a comprehension.

Comment: How is a dict comprehension inherently bad to read? It's probably bad to read only for those who just came to Python from other programming languages. It's an elegant construct that's both concise and efficient.

Comment: Lets analyze the comprehension: it's a dict comprehension which are inherently bad to read (but absolutely good to go often)
the keys are constructed via three type conversions and a method call
The values: You generate and unpack a counter, that is a frozenset of a counter's items and have another loop in there and a few functions calls. It may be functional but its very bad style and teaching that on here isn't the way to go

Comment: I mainly do python and they just are imo. As for the rest: that's not opinion, that's fact. That's logic that doesn't belong in comprehensions

Comment: Actually this is the perfect result for me but i can't use the modules you used on my code..I have to do it with simpler way..

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using the stuff I've mentioned:

```
from collections import Counter

a = [(i,j,k) for i in range(1, 7) for j in range(1, 7) for k in range(1, 7)]
c = Counter(frozenset(x) for x in a if len(set(x)) == 3)

counter_most_common = c.most_common(1)[0][1]
for combination, counter in c.items():
    if counter == counter_most_common:
        print(f"{combination} is one of the most common combinations! It exists {counter} times")
```

As you can see, they're all equally likely, which makes perfect sense if you think about it